# What is the Pythonic way to avoid reference before assignment errors in enclosing scopes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm speaking about the general case. Here's an example:

```
c = 1
def a():
    def b():
        print(c)
    b()
    c = 2

a()
```

This code will return the following error:
`NameError: free variable 'c' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope`. While the logical assumption is that the output should be `1`. What is the Pythonic solution to this issue? Use the `global` or `nonlocal` statements (which I don't like)? Maybe just avoid such situations, where multiple scopes share variables with identical names?

Comment: Avoid it, or pass it as a parameter. `a(c)` when calling `a()`. Either that or use global.

Comment: Use decent variable names? Avoid using globals? Avoid so much nesting? Honestly, I have never run into this issue myself, this should *not* be a common problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Passing it as a parameter**

When passing a outside variable as a parameter, avoid reusing names unless it's not possible that this variable can handle any other variable as parameter, then it doesn't really matter otherwise it will be confusing if you pass `d` the next time and you do operations on `c` within the function.

Secondly, **the value of** `c` **will not get modified within the function** even if changing name from `param` to `c` (it has very little meaning) when passing as a variable because it's not considered as a global varaible, even tho the variable is an object it will only be a object in this function unless you pass it into a class.

```
c = 1
def a(param):
    def b():
        print(param)
    b()
    param = 2

a(c)
```

You would need to stick to the global option if you don't want to pass it as a parameter and you still want to affect `c` outside of your function.
The global option **will** affect the "outside" c variable as your want it to.. but this is not really considered best practice, avid it if possible.

```
c = 1
def a():
    global c
    def b():
        print(c)
    b()
    c = 2

a()
```

## Here's what i would recommend:

```
c = 1
def a(param):
    def b():
        print(param)
    b()
    param = 2
    return param

c = a(c)
```

Or even:

```
c = 1
def b(param):
    print(param)
def a(param):
    b(param)
    param = 2
    return param

c = a(c)
```

Comment: Another recomendation is to avoid nested function as much as possible. In Python there is really no need to have them, at all.. Set up a class if you want to execute different functions on the same variable or just have two separate functions, they can be called just as easily.