# calling a second function within another function

Tags: python, function

I would like to open a file using the a_reader function. I would then like to use a second function to print the file. I want to do this because I would like to be able to call the open file function later without printing it. Any ideas on the best way to do this? Here is a sample code that I know does not work but it may help explain what I want to do

```
 def main ():        
        a_reader = open ('C:\Users\filexxx.csv','r')      
        fileName = a_reader.read()
        a_reader.close()

    def print():
        print fileName



main()
print()
```

Comment: Well, you define two functions and you call them. It's as easy as that. Are you really intending to define the print() function *inside* the main() function? Or is that just an indentation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this day old thread: [What is the Pythonic way to avoid reference before assignment errors in enclosing scopes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16363387/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-reference-before-assignment-errors-in-enclosin/16363430#16363430)

The user in that post had the exact same issue, he wanted to define a function within another function (in your case `main`) as adviced both by me and others you don't nest functions!

There's no need to use nested functions in Python, it just adds useless complexity that doesn't give you any real practical advantages.

I would do:

```
def main ():
    a_reader = open ('C:\\Users\\filexxx.csv','r')      

    fileName = a_reader.read()

    a_reader.close()
    return fileName

print(main())
```

or

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        a_reader = open ('C:\\Users\\filexxx.csv','r')
        self.fileName = a_reader.read()
        a_reader.close()
    def _print(self):
        print(self.fileName)

a = main()
a._print()
```

It's **never** a good idea to define your function-/class-names as the same as the default Python functions/classes. `print` being one of them.

---

But here's a solution if you really wanna go with your original setup:

```
def main ():
    a_reader = open ('C:\\Users\\filexxx.csv','r')
    fileName = a_reader.read()
    a_reader.close()

    def _print():
        print fileName

    _print()

main()
```

Oh, and btw.. strings with backslashes should be escaped or you need to use `r'..'` :)

Comment: +1 for great answer 0 particularly like the 2 examples:`print(main())` and the `class ` version.

Answer (score 0):

First - you can't name your function as print as this is a function already existing in python and will return an error.
And it seems like a [class is what you are looking for](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) to be your main(), not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to rock-the-boat here,  I actually agree with the above two answers. Perhaps a class is the right way to go, and almost certainly it would be unwise to override the native print() function.

One of Python's strengths is that it covers a whole range of programming paradigms. You want a direct, procedural implementation -Python! You want to re-use your code and make some generic, reusable classes - OOP and Python! Python also allows for functional programming - Python's built-in functions `map` and `zip` are classic examples of functional programming.

Not saying that this is what was being asked in this question, but you could do this functionally:

```
def my_name_function(n):
    return ' '.join(['This is my Name:', n])

def say_hello(x):
    print('Hello, world!', x)

say_hello(my_name_function('Nick'))
--> Hello, world! This is my Name: Nick
```

Again, I don't think this is what the question is really asking. I do agree that, in this case, the best implementation would be a class, in the OOP sense. (Probably the more Pythonic way to go even :p)

But, to say there is no need for nested functions in Python, when Python leaves this option open to us? When Python has recently (over the last few years) opened the door to functional programming concepts??? It does have its advantages (and disadvantages) - if it didn't there would be no way that Guido, as the Benevolent Dictator for Life, would have opened this box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `a_reader` to be 'function', you should call it as a function and not use it as a variable. In [python](/questions/tagged/python) that would be by using `a_reader()`.

The following implements a class `Reader` of which an instance `a_reader` can be called as a function. Only at the point of calling is the file opened. Like others already have indicated, you should escape backslashes in string literals (`"..\\.."`), or use raw strings (`r"..\.."`). It is also good practise to put the normal code in python file under an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement, that way you can import functions/classes from the file without invoking the (test) code.

```
class Reader(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self._file_name = file_name
        self._fp = None

    def __call__(self):
        if self._fp:
            return self._fp
        return open(self._file_name, 'r')

def main():
    a_reader = Reader(r"C:\\Users\\filexxx.csv")
    # no file opened yet
    file_content = a_reader().read()
    a_reader().close()
    print file_content

if __name__ == '__main__': # only call main() if not imported
    main()
```